# Python: Class instance "has no attribute" while passed to function in another module

Tags: python, class, inheritance, import, module

I have a problem with passing class instance to function in another module.

Here's the code:
(in module "base"):

```
from physics import *
...
class CellsArray(blist):
    def getCollidingCells(self, cell):
        diff = ((0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (0,-1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), (-1, 1), (1, -1))
        result = []
        for x, y in diff:
            c = self.getCellByCoords(cell.x + x, cell.y + y)
            if c:
                result.append(c)
        if result:
            return result
        else:
            return None

    def getCellByCoords(self, x, y):
        for c in self:
            if c.x == x and c.y == y:
                return c
        return None

    def getCellById(self, uid):
        for c in self:
            if id(c) == uid:
                return c
        return None

class World():
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.cells = CellsArray([])
        ...
        self.procedures = [freeFallAccel, airEffects, specialProcedures,
                           moveCells, collisionsTest]

    ...
    def step(self):
        if not self.paused:
            for f in self.procedures:
                f(self.cells) #here the collisionsTest function is being called
```

(in module "physics"):

```
import base
...
def collisionsTest(cells):
    for c in cells:
        cells.getCollidingCells(cells.getCellByCoords(c.x, c.y))
```

When I load the "base" module into interactive interpreter (or create CellsArray instance inside the "base" module), everything seems fine:
(interactive interpreter example):

```
>>> a = CellsArray([])
>>> a.append(Cell())
>>> a.getCollidingCells(a[0])
#returns None
>>> a.getCollidingCells
<bound method CellsArray.getCollidingCells of blist([<__main__.Cell instance at 0x7f847e8fa170>])>
```

But when `physics.collisionsTest` is executed somewhere inside the "base" module, something wrong happens:

```
    cells.getCollidingCells(cells.getCellByCoords(c.x, c.y))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getCollidingCells'
```

However, if I add `print type(cells); print cells.getCollidingCells` to the collisionsTest function (before the `for c in cells ...`), it returns :

```
<class 'base.CellsArray'>
<bound method CellsArray.getCollidingCells of blist([<base.Cell instance at 0x7f2e4a7d1638>, ...])>
```

I feel that something is wrong with importing "physics" module, but I've tried almost every available methods of importing that module and I still get that error.
Module "physics" uses some variables and classes from module "base", so I can't simply remove "`import base`".

Is there any way to resolve that problem, or I'll have to move all functions and constants from "physics" back to "base"?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org for more info

Comment: Presumably on the line `cells.getCollidingCells(cells.getCellByCoords(c.x, c.y))`, cells is a list, not a CellsArray. You'd have to show us where `collisionTest` is being called if you want more debugging help.

Comment: `CellsArray` itself is a list. It extends the `blist` class, which extends base Python `list` class. `blist` is stored in external, third-party Python library.

Answer (score 0):

`cells` is a `list` of `CellsArray`, but you are expecting it to be an individual `CellsArray`.

Perhaps `collisionsTest` should be:

```
def collisionsTest(cells):
    for c in cells:
        c.getCollidingCells(c.getCellByCoords(c.x, c.y))
```

Comment: No, `collisionsTest` calls `getCollidingCells` method of given CellsArray (`cells`). CellsArray itself finds Cell by coordinates and returns colliding Cells.

Comment: From your error message, I can assure you that `cells` is **not** a `CellsArray`. It is a `list`. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I have already mentioned that `CellsArray` indeed is a list : it extends the `blist` class.

Comment: Be that as it may, `cells` is not a `CellsArray`, it is a `list`. You can convince yourself of this by adding `print type(cells)` to `collistionsTest`.